# Apache spark - JDBC write , intermediate commits

Tags: sql-server, apache-spark, jdbc, pyspark

I am working on writing to Microsoft SQL Server using Spark from hive, process works with great speed.

But there is big issue, that each tasks until completes does not commits - which utilizes transaction log of the database and can cause impacts to other running jobs.

I need to have some way to commits at regular interval ( 10000 K  or so) .
Can someone please suggest how this can be done?

Comment: Your explanation of the problem is insufficient. Can you be more specific? You can partition the data in the way you need.

Comment: There are billion rows in some of the SRC tables, hence I can not really partition into those many tasks ; and my theory of Spark committing results at the end of each task completion is not 100% solid. Usually with all the ETL tools there are options ( like SSIS / informatica ) - where they commit after X number of rows to not to affect the database, I was hoping there should be some way with Spark as well.

Comment: Have you found evidence otherwise to my answer?

Comment: So why are you using Big Data and then writing to SQL Server? If I may ask.

Comment: We need it for reporting purposes - we have bad experience of pulling from hdp to reporting tools

Comment: That's an informative point. For others.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with JDBC.

With sqoop export there is a possibility.